# New-Item Behavior Changes When Using Runspace to Run Command Remotely

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am using VB.Net to open a Powershell runspace using `WSManConnectionInfo`. The connection works fine. I am trying to run a New-Item command in order to create a new virtual directory.

```
New-Item "IIS:\Sites\ExternalInventory FTP\TestVT"  -Type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath "C:\"
```

The command works fine when running it locally on the server. However, when ran remotely through the runspace I get an error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'physicalPath'.

I initially tried to use use the `New-WebVirtualDirectory` command to create the virtual directory, but this led to other errors. I need to use `New-Item`.

What is causing the difference in behavior of the New-Item command, and how can I use it to create a new virtual directory through the runspace?

Note: I have tried other commands through the runspace and they seem to work as expected.

**EDITS**

I know that the New-Item command does not have the parameter "physicalPath" listed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6

The New-Item command is used in multiple places in the docs to create virtual directory with the physicalPath parameter. See links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6

https://forums.iis.net/t/1223546.aspx?New+WebVirtualDirectory+does+not+work+when+invoked+remotely+and+a+UNC+path+is+used

Comment: `New-Item` doesn't *have* a `-PhysicalPath` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of editing to include that. Please see my edits. Also, why would the command work locally then with the `-PhysicalPath` parameter?

Comment: That's one link to a forum post that is wrong.  I suspect it works locally because it's using the `IIS:` drive and support for `*-Item` cmdlets depends on the drive you're using.

Comment: And the docs link is wrong also? `PS IIS:\Sites> New-Item iis:\Sites\TestSite -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:TestSite"} -physicalPath c:\test` Quoted from the docs where they use that command: "Using the -physicalPath argument is pretty straightforward. But you might ask yourself why the -bindings argument looks so complex."

Comment: I can't find that example anywhere on the docs.

Comment: Are you explicitly loading the WebAdministration module in your runspace? Try adding a line for `ipmo WebAdministration` before your `New-Item` line, and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thought having the module on the host would be enough. Importing the WebAdministration module in the runspace seems to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I needed to include the WebAdministration module in my script.

Thanks TheMadTechnitian